# Pouring through automation logs with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I could not think of a good title for my question. I have an automated warehouse with conveyors moving boxes. Each box has a unique parcel number. There are dozens of scanners telling the boxes where to go. Each time a scanner sees a box it creates two rows in the table (Sort and Confirm) that look like this:

```
    time          scanner    type    parcel
12:00:19.635        s15      Sort     83128
12:00:20.3          s15      Confirm  83128
12:02:05.857        s18      Sort     94387 
12:02:07.692        s18      Confirm  94387
```

So, each unique parcel number and each unique scanner has many entries. How can I write a query that would tell me what parcels have begun their journey (seen by s15) but not yet reached the middle part (seen by s71 or s72)? I am also considering duration; how long did it take for the box to go from s15 to s71? Or maybe that is best left for a second question. Thanks!

Comment: Would this be based on the `confirm` record or the `sort` record?

Comment: Are the scanner numbers ordered by number? So first comes s15 then s16 then ... s71. My idea is "Find all rows with scanner number < 71"

Comment: I have been basing my queries on Sort but I think either would be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many gaps in the scanner numbers and occasionally they go out of order. A box will see scanner 80 before it sees s71. But that is an interesting thought to consider.

Comment: OK, so it should be checked if 15 is passed but not 71/72? Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8bc963c8662365180fb8b65937732722)

```
SELECT parcel, passed_scanners
FROM (
    SELECT
        parcel,
        array_agg(scanner) as passed_scanners
    FROM
        scanners
    GROUP BY parcel
)s
WHERE 's15' = ANY(passed_scanners) AND NOT (ARRAY['s71', 's72'] && passed_scanners)
```

1. Aggregate all passed `scanner_id`s for each parcel
2. Filter all parcel rows that contains #15 in `passed_scanners` but neither #71 nor #72 (`&&` operator for two arrays check if array elements are contained by both arrays - called *array overlap*)

---

The second part is a different query because in the first you ask for parcels that still not reached the final scanner. In the second part you want do calculate the duration for all parcels that finally reached s71.

```
SELECT parcel, duration
FROM (
    SELECT
        parcel,
        MAX(time) FILTER (WHERE scanner IN ('s71', 's72')) -
        MIN(time) FILTER (WHERE scanner = 's15') AS duration,
        array_agg(scanner) as passed_scanners
    FROM
        scanners
    GROUP BY parcel
)s
WHERE 's15' = ANY(passed_scanners) AND (ARRAY['s71', 's72'] && passed_scanners)
```

1. Again aggregate all passed scanner_ids for each parcel
2. Give out the first time for scanner 15 and the last time for either scanner 71 or 72. Build the difference to get the duration.
3. Filter all parcel rows that contains #15 in `passed_scanners` and either #71 or #72

**Please notice**: Without any date component in your `time` column the result for duration might not work if the parcel is scanned over midnight. Then your start at s15 could be at 23h and the destination would be at 1h. The time difference would be `(1 - 23) = -22`. To solve this I strongly recommend to save the whole timestamp with date part.

Otherwise you have to check: If `duration < 0` then add 24 hours (but what if the parcel needs more then 24 hours? How to know that you do not need to add 48 hours?)

Comment: @Tuffgong Updated the answer with calculation of duration. Is this what you expected (Then please do not forget to accept/upvote)?

Comment: Edit: Simplified the query. No need for converting the scanner_ids into pure integers with added requirements.

Comment: Wow! This is looking good. It might be perfect! There is a lot to pour through but at the very least I think I can get where I need to go with some tweeking if I am not there already. I really appreciate it. Thank you!